# How to enable Start Menu in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, startmenu

Can anyone give me some hack or provide some way, by which I can enable the `Start Menu` in Windows 8.

I am finding hard to use Windows 8 without `Start Menu`.

I dont have any problem, If I need to write a Custom Code in .Net to enable it.

[image: Start Menu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a web page which provides some nice features and tricks for windows called neowin.

On this page I found this article: http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-8-how-to-re-enable-the-classic-start-menu

I hope this is what you´re looking for :)

EDIT: I also have Windows 8 and I´m using this Trick without problems :)

EDIT 2: 
**This won´t work for build 9200 or newer!** I just got the new build and i tried to execute this trick but after restart my Windows told me to "Refresh" or "Reset" my Operating System. after refreshing my win 8 all my apps and programs were erased.

Greets,

Paedow

Comment: Will this also work for Release version

Comment: Yes it will, the Windows registry is one of the first things being completed on a Windows OS, want say: the registry entries now existing will exist in the release version, too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the windows key (bottom left corner of your keyboard) to get the start menu. Hope this helps. Or you can set your theme to an earlier version of windows that has the start menu.